# Is the inverse of $\tan\frac{\pi}{2}x$ differentiable?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I know that function $f(x)=\tan\frac{\pi}{2}x$ is bijective. Is the inverse of this function differentiable? How can I prove that?

Comment: Do you have an interval you are working in?

Comment: Do you mean the inverse of tan(x) or tan(xpi/2) ?

Comment: function f is from (-1,1) to R. inverse of tan(pi/2 x).

Comment: Let’s take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164995/inverse-function-differentiability-proof